# Google maps API maximal coordinate length?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

This may sound weird, but i need to know what the maximum amount of digits in a coordinate in the Google maps API is.

Say for an example, i use their "Web Services" API to find an address, then what is the longest possible lat/lng number? like xxx.xxxxx...

I see them referring to a 10 digit number (not counting the dot) in their documentation for the web services api, but i don't know if that's the max?..
Personally i haven't seen anything more than 7 digits after the dot returned, but i know google can at least search for a seemingly endless coordinate.

If anyone knows for sure what the longest coordinate you can expect returned is, please let me know.

Comment: It's probably "whatever our code returns" as always with Google stuff. "Don't ask we don't know or we don't care about you".

Answer (score 0):

SQL-wise:

Latitude/Longitude should use FLOAT/DOUBLE precision.

It's definitely not recommend to use e.g. VARCHAR(20) because numeric comparisons would fail for sure.

API-wise:

Same applies for the Maps JS API;
about the various Data-APIs I'm not sure (and have no time to test that)

(probably just precision-reduction/proximity...)

[PHP Manual - Floating point numbers:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

**update**  just being down-voted (5 years later) without a reason (most likely by someone, who failed to comprehend)... while newer versions of mySQL even feature a [Point](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html) datatype, in order to represent coordinates... still API wise, the data is always posted as `String`.

Comment: The question was not how to use the data or implement it in a system, i have that part covered. Allso, i did not ask to the JS API, i asked to the "Web services" API. I simply wanted to know the maximal number of decimals, and your answer has nothing to do with that at all...

Comment: You asked for the maps API and in the 2nd line for any data API.
And it's definably correct that the Maps API uses float precision.

Comment: LocalSearch API *seems* to be more accurate than the GeoCoder API (by quality of results, not by the digits after the dot). user-generated content might be more precise.

Comment: indeed - the data-type defines the maximal precision.